# JavaScript: Allow characters with Regex but exclude certain patterns of those characters

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there a way to allow a certain range of characters, but also *exclude certain patterns* of these allowed characters?

For example, let's say you're searching for a range of letters:

```
[A-Za-z]
```

but you *don't* want to match a certain pattern of these accepted characters, for example:

```
abc
```

I've been trying to craft an expression for a while and have had no luck. What I've been able to come up with was:

```
([A-Za-z][^abc])*
```

But this doesn't provide the behavior I'm looking for. Is there a way to search a range of characters and exclude certain patters of the accepted characters?

**EDIT**

To clarify, I was wondering if I could be able to still match the characters besides the unaccepted pattern. For example, if we had:

```
SomeTextabcMoreText
```

and `abc` is an illegal pattern, is there a way to match the legal characters and yield some result similar to:

```
SomeText
MoreText
```

Comment: Are you expecting to get just one occurrence or multiple occurrences of `abc`?

Comment: @NeilTwist I'm expecting any amount of `abc`

Comment: How about `str.replace(/abc/g, '\x00').match(whatever)`?

Comment: I don't understand why there's a downvote - if my question is inappropriate I'd appreciate feedback

Comment: @georg Interesting.. this makes me think that Regex maybe isn't the correct approach for this problem - maybe I can just parse the string with the illegal patterns as delimiters

Comment: I've had a play. I'm ready to admit that regex is not the right answer for this!

Comment: @NeilTwist After really taking a step back and looking at my problem again, I agree with you. I think it'd make more sense to just parse the string and use the illegal pattern as a delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that regexes are the right solution to this.

There are two option depending upon language:

1. `String.replace` - If you're looking to just output the results.
2. `String.split` if you're looking to tokenize the results.

```js
$('#replace').text("SomeabcStringabcwithsomeabccharacters".replace(/abc/g, ""));
$('#split').text(JSON.stringify("SomeabcStringabcwithsomeabccharacters".split("abc")));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='replace'></div>
<div id='split'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After taking a step back and analyzing my particular problem more, I realize that Regex wouldn't be the best way to solve this.

It would make more sense to parse the string using the illegal pattern as a delimiter:

```
var data = 'SomeTextabcMoreText';
var illegalPattern = 'abc';

console.log(data.split(illegalPattern)); // => ["SomeText", "MoreText"]
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/47dbLmho/)

Comment: I came to the same conclusion in the end. I think that Regexes are good for matching and returning strings, but for this sort of thing, perhaps they add more complication than it's worth. Also, remember that someone may have to maintain it one day.